# How do I distribute my program from a Visual Studio Solution?

Tags: visual-studio, release

I recently created a program in Visual Studio that I'd like to share with the world, up untill this point all of the programming I did was only for personal use so I have no experience preparing a program for release.

I found some information about building for release so I tried it but I ended up with 5 different files (3 of which are needed for succesfull execution):

- the .exe file
- a .dll file of the same name
- a .pdb file of the same name (not needed for succesfull execution)
- a runtimeconfig.json file
- a deps.json file (not needed for succesfull execution)
  I'd like to just distribute a single .exe file, like a portable version. Is this possible?

Comment: [Single-file deployment and executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=vs)

Comment: What kind of app is this? If it's a command line tool, consider a .NET Tool. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools

Comment: You can also use a setup builder for distribution. If the application grows and/or special steps are required during installation, this is probably the most convenient way for your users.